# Linked-servers SQL Server 2012 permission?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to understand the linked-servers in SQL Server Studio 2012 that I am using to develop a big report. I have looked through some of the post but I didn't see anything related to permission or how to do it with non-default instance servers that we have. My first question is: can I use create linked-server querying when I only have read permission? Second: I would appreciate if someone can elaborate more on the syntax. Below is the syntax that I am having problem with. Our server name is not just the server name but it has servername\databasename due to IT's reason for a non-default instance (this is what our IT department told me).

```
SELECT *
FROM   [server1\databse1 name].[dbo].[table name]. tab1
       INNER JOIN [server2\database2 name].[dbo].[table name] tab2
       ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID`
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. can I use create linked-server querying when I only have read permission?

Answer:  No you will need sysadmin permissions to add a linked server. If you only have read permissions on the server you will need to ask your DBA to do it for you.

2. I would appreciate if someone can elaborate more on the syntax. Below is the syntax that I am having problem.....

Your syntax will be something like this...

Assuming `databse1Name` is located on the Linked server and `database2Name` is on the server where you are logged on.

```
SELECT * FROM 
[ServerName].[databse1Name].[dbo].[table name]. tab1 
INNER JOIN [database2Name].[dbo].[table name] tab2 
ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

If it is a specific Instance on the linked server then you would write your query something like...

```
SELECT * FROM 
[ServerName\InstanceName].[databse1Name].[dbo].[table name]. tab1 
INNER JOIN [database2Name].[dbo].[table name] tab2 
ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```